# The custom init method

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to figure out an error: **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    var mapView :AGSMapView?
    mapViewHelper = GeoneMapViewHepler.init(mapView: mapView!, mapViewDelegate: self)
}
```

---

```
class GeoneMapViewHepler: NSObject {

    var mapViewModule :GeoneMapViewModel?
    var mapView :AGSMapView?
    var mapViewDelegate :AnyObject?

init(mapView mp: AGSMapView, mapViewDelegate md: AnyObject) {
    mapView = mp
    mapViewDelegate = md
    super.init()
    }

}
```

I spent half a day，but I don't find the key...

thanks for answers ！

Comment: this error is obvious because the optional mapView var is nil and you are assigning the value to the required variable inside the init function.

Comment: you should have to have a  look of this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu) this may help ..and the problem is sure accessing nil object by you.

Comment: thanks,it has been solved.^_^

Answer (score 0):

Put `MainViewController`'s initialization code in `viewDidLoad`. `mapView` is set only once the view has loaded.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapViewHelper = GeoneMapViewHepler.init(mapView: mapView!, mapViewDelegate: self)

    ...
}
```